# UNNotificationAction with Firebase remote notification is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, nsnotificationcenter

I am stuck for few days for trying to add UNNotificationAction buttons for my remote notifications that support iOS 9, 10 and 11. I followed all the steps from multiple tutorials, most of them are using local notification to show the UNNotificationAction which are working so far. However it doesn't work for my remote notification. I am able to send remote notification via Firebase. Please do let me know if some parts of my code are incorrect or missing parts to configure UNNotificationAction buttons.

Those code in my AppDelegate,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    requestNotificationAuthorization(application: application)
    }
    return true
}

func requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {granted, error in

            if (granted)
            {
                let viewAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "viewAction", title: "View", options: [])

                let closeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "closeAction", title: "Close", options: [])
                // 2
                let buttonCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "buttonCategory", actions: [viewAction, closeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
                // 3
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([buttonCategory])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                print("Granted")
            }
        })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: notificationAction() as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}

func notificationAction() -> NSSet {
    let firstAction: UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    firstAction.identifier = "First_Action"
    firstAction.title = "View"
    firstAction.activationMode = .foreground
    firstAction.isDestructive = false
    firstAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false

    let secondAction: UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    secondAction.identifier = "Second_Action"
    secondAction.title = "Close"
    secondAction.activationMode = .background
    secondAction.isDestructive = false
    secondAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false

    //category
    let firstCategory : UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    firstCategory.identifier = "buttonCategory"

    let defaultAction = [firstAction,secondAction]
    let mininalAction = [firstAction,secondAction]

    firstCategory.setActions(defaultAction, for: UIUserNotificationActionContext.default)
    firstCategory.setActions(mininalAction, for: UIUserNotificationActionContext.minimal)

    //NSSet of category
    let categories = NSSet(object: firstCategory)

    return categories
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
// iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert])
}

// iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if(response.actionIdentifier == "viewAction"){
        print("viewing Action")
    }

    if(response.actionIdentifier == "closeAction"){
        print("closing Action")
    }

    completionHandler()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to making iOS remote notifications via Firebase work, and many of them are not code-related. First make sure that you are able to send/receive a simple text-only notification, without Actions.

Once that's working, then see if you are receiving the built-in actions, UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier and UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier.

If that works, then you should only need the code from your delegate methods and `requestNotificationAuthorization` method - your `notificationAction()` method seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I managed to find the solution. I am using postman to send the notification because I need to display image whereas firebase currently is not able to have separate parameter inside the json. Yes you are right, once the user can send basic text message then setup the notification action and category. Inside the json, include click_action and it will appear the action.